# "watch folder" in linux version of Mendeley Desktop

Tags: ntfs, mendeley

I am using mendeley on Ubuntu 16.04. the problem is, I can't add set "watch folder" to my article folder on drives D. In other words, "watch folder" in Ubuntu version of mendely is limited to "root drive" of linux, while there is no such limitation in windows version and one can set the "watch folder" to any folder in any drive (drive D, E,...) is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works also in 16.04, I'm working on Ubuntu 17.10.
I had the same problem until I realized that I can access other drives from the root. Do the following: in Mendeley, click on watch folder and follow this path:

```
/ >> media >> [username] >> [Drive]
```

- `[username]` is your user name in the computer.
- `[Drive]` is the name of the Drive that you are looking for.

My additional drive was there and it is working for me.